# How to get navigable links to pages from a site using jsoup?

Tags: java, html, web-crawler, jsoup, anchor

I am implementing a basic crawler with the purpose of later use in a vulnerability scanner. I am using jsoup for the connection/retrieving and parsing of html document.

I supply manually the base/root of the intended site(www.example.com) and connect.

```
...
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT);
Document htmlDocument = connection.get();
this.htmlDocument = htmlDocument;
...
```

Then i retrieve all the links on the page.

```
...
Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");
...
```

After this I loop between the links and try to get the links to all the pages on the site.

```
for (Element link : linksOnPage) {
                this.links.add(link.absUrl("href"));
    }
```

The problem is as follows. Depending on the links I get, some might not be links to new pages or not even links to pages at all. As an example a got links like:

- https://example.example.com/webmail
- http://193.231.21.13
- mailto:example.example@exampl.com

What i need some help whit is the filtering of the links so that i get only links to new pages of the same root/base site.

Comment: Check if link starts with domain name: `link.startsWith("http://www.ics.uci.edu/")`

Comment: The Element object in jsoup does not have a method like "startsWith" and a link that does not start with the base domain (/pages.page2.html) might still be on the same site just using js for navigation.

Comment: Take String url of `Element link` object. And call startsWith on `url`. Links that use js for navigation must have common properties. You can filter by them

Comment: Use `String absUrl = linkElement.attr("href"); if(absUrl.startsWith("http://www.ics.uci.edu/")){//this is url within your site}`

Comment: This solved some of the unusable links but i found out that there are still links of this format that can lead to documents or images. Ex: http://www.example.com/wp-content/gallery/despre-noi/3-2.jpg or http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/17-HGR-890.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is easy. Check if absUrl ends with image format or js or css:

```
if(absUrl.startsWith("http://www.ics.uci.edu/") && !absUrl.matches(".*\\.(bmp|gif|jpg|png|js|css)$")) 
{

    //here absUrl starts with domain name and is not image or js or css
}
```

Comment: This works fine for most of the cases since you can just add new extensions as needed but there has to be a better universal solution. From here https://jsoup.org/apidocs/ i found that the original selector "Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");" can be modified with regex like img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g)]. The problem is that i find it difficult to construct a regex that excludes generic file extensions beside .html.